# V-Html has "v-on:click" line but rendered as pure HTML

Tags: vue.js

I have my

```
v-html="customButtons"
```

and I want to insert in this v-html a v-on:click with custom function like this

```
<div class="v-m-button"> 
                        <button type="button" id="btn-cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                v-on:click="saveButtonClick()">
                            <span>Save</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

^code above will be pass to `customButtons` v-html tag

help me with this thanks!

Comment: You cannot use Vue syntax (ie, `v-bind`, `v-on`, `{{ ... }}`) in injected HTML strings. Perhaps use a dynamic component instead

Comment: How can I do that? Can I have an example?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: `v-html` is for rendering pure HTML, not Vue templates.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and here are the solutions I found:

- On Vue 2, there is [this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/53615036178/) that might help some people: https://www.programmersought.com/article/53615036178/
- On Vue 3, there is this library [over there](https://github.com/mattelen/vue3-runtime-template#readme), that I used with success.

However, as mentioned by others elsewhere there are a good reasons why this is made so hard to do. Maybe the security reasons are not a big concern for you. But say that your app grows and is so widely used that  performance becomes your main concern; then you may want to rebuild your front-end using Svelte instead of Vue. Then, all your `@click=this...` (vue specific code) in the html sent by you API will become almost unusable by the Svelte app, at which point you might tell to yourself:
"It would have been way simpler to just send those as json metadata and build the appropriate interface instead of trying to 'win time' by brute-forcingly favoring a bad data structure."